# AutoLayout in UITableViewCell contentView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, constraints

I'm trying to programmatically create constraints to center this pink UIView in a UITableViewCell. However, when I add the constraints, they don't apply and I get a message in the console that says that some `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints` can't be simultaneously satisfied.

So when I set `cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, I get this message in the console :

> "Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of the contentView of a UITableViewCell is not supported and will result in undefined behavior, as this property is managed by the owning UITableViewCell".

The view does get centered, but the console says I shouldn't change this property.

How can I achieve this?

[Before setting the property to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcE0p.png)

[After setting the property to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJkL.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please show your constraint creation code?

Comment: Also make sure the constraints are not duplicated due to cell reuse. You might add same constraints twice or more. Also I recommend against dynamic constraints on table view cells, you might have performance issues there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` manages its `contentView` manually. In other words, `UIKit` relies on the cells' `contentView` having translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints being `True` so Changing the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of the contentView of a UITableViewCell is not supported and will result in undefined behavior.

Don't do this:

```
cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

So, here is the full function for adding `UIView` in a UITableViewCell should be look like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    //if already added the subview?
    if cell.contentView.subviews.count == 0 {

        let view = UIView() //your pinkView

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

        cell.contentView.addSubview(view)

        view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know this .constraint thing existed

Answer (score 20):

Also, make sure that in xib of your cell, Layout should be selected to

"Autoresizing Mask"

**and not** "Inferred (Autoresizing Mask)"

as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: This should be the correct solution, you saved my day thanks @Ghulam Rasool

Comment: this answer saved my time, thanks man!

Comment: This is the answer for me.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but the accepted answer also is valid.

Comment: I have spent literally my full 3 days looking for this not knowing why digging into CollectionView itself. this works and you are GOAT. thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to `contentView` of tableview cell.

You only need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to the view which is added dynamically and for `IBOutlets` `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` by default.